# Does Geddy have support for has and belongs to many associations?

Tags: node.js, geddy

I'm developing a Geddy application where I need a "has and belongs to many" association. Is this possible? It looks like only hasOne, hasMany, and belongsTo associations are supported in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stacking the associations?

```
this.hasOne('thing')
this.hasMany('things')
```

You should be able to. Otherwise, [submit an issue](https://github.com/mde/geddy/issues) or hop on the #geddy freenode IRC channel and we'll help you out.